# Avoid Mandrill errors with Sentry

Tags: python, django, mandrill, sentry

I have installed a Sentry instance on my server, and I want to configure it to send alert emails using [Mandrill](https://mandrillapp.com) and its Django integration [djrill](http://djrill.readthedocs.org). Here's the relevant settings in the `sentry.conf.py` file I'm using:

```
EXTRA_INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'djrill',
)
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'djrill.mail.backends.djrill.DjrillBackend'

MANDRILL_API_KEY = '[... Mandril API key ...]'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'my-mandrill-allowed@email.address'
SERVER_EMAIL = 'my-mandrill-allowed@email.address'
```

And this setup works, except for the part that for some reason Mandrill doesn't allow setting the `Message-Id` header:

```
NotSupportedByMandrillError: Invalid message header 'Message-Id' - Mandrill only allows Reply-To and X-* headers
```

(This exception is raised by djrill, is not a response from Mandrill)

Which is set by Sentry [here](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry/blob/7aa7d9aca1b22206fc8870b71f97da578b515b7b/src/sentry/utils/email.py#L96):

```
class MessageBuilder(object):
    # ...
    @cached_property
    def message_id(self):
        if self.reference is not None:
            return email_id_for_model(self.reference)
```

I have managed to make it work by editing that method and make it always return `None`, so no `Message-Id` header is set in the email. But I don't like to edit/patch 3rd party code and I have no idea if that header is needed elsewhere.

How to accomplish this correctly? Switching from Mandrill is not an option right now.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can't easily change Sentry's behavior, as far as I can tell, I'd suggest implementing a subclass of `DjrillBackend` that removes the `Message-Id` header before the messages are sent. Something like (untested):

```
class HeaderRemovingBackend(DjrillBackend):
    def send_messages(self, email_messages):
        for message in email_messages:
            if 'Message-Id' in message.extra_headers:
                del message.extra_headers['Message-Id']
        super(HeaderRemovingBackend, self).send_messages(email_messages)
```

Comment: Well, I resolved it installing the latest version of Djrill. But I'm going to accept this answer because I was going to implement it if upgrading wasn't an option. Thanks!